# Using MvcScaffold, I'm getting "Sequence contains no elements" for most files, for each model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

[image: Example error; I try to *Scaffold Controller Region -Repository*]
Example error; I try to *Scaffold Controller Region -Repository*

**Region class**

```
public class Region
{
    public int RegionId { get; set; }

    public string RegionCode { get; set; }
    public string ApiUrl { get; set; }

    public Universe[] Universes { get; set; }
}
```

The error repeats essentially for each file it tries to generate (the views, mostly).

I'm not sure what information to include other than this, because I have *no* clue what causes it. I've tried searching for a solution, but most solutions seems unrelated to my particular issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I will suggest to you is to replace the `Array` by a `List` or better an generic interface `ICollection`. And then try again. Working with array you need to intialize it in the constructor.

```
   public class Region
  {
    public int RegionId { get; set; }

    public string RegionCode { get; set; }
    public string ApiUrl { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Universe> Universes { get; set; }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem immediately after submitting with a last-resort option.

I changed:

```
public Universe[] Universes { get; set; }
```

To:

```
public ICollection<Universe> Universes { get; set; }
```

Then I ran the Scaffold command again, and it worked perfectly. Strange!